# How do you type a number with a bar symbol over it?

Tags: debian, kde, unicode, math

100 divided by 3 equals 33.3 [bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)). How can I put a bar symbol over the three like this:

[image]

You'd think there would be 9 Unicode characters dedicated to this, but I couldn't find them.

Comment: Found https://fsymbols.com/generators/overline/  at https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087009/6047827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [combining overline](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/0305.html) symbol (U+0305):  ̅3 (at least for me in Firefox it doesn't print as nicely as advertised), see this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline#Unicode) for more details.

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>0305</kbd> and then the letter/number you want overlined.

If you want something more complex (e.g. for more repeating numbers) you need to write in a specialized tool for writing math like LaTeX ([Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/index.html) with Markdown + LaTeX is great if you want something fast and relatively easy to write) or LibreOffice Math.

Comment: [Vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol))

Comment: I can't seem to get your instructions to work as I type into the [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/) text editor. And, when I attempt them in this comment box I simply just get: u0305.

Comment: ̅Ah, you have to press <enter> afterwards.

Comment: You need to hold Ctrl+Shift the entire time. In KDE you can also use KCharSelect and copy the symbol from there.

Comment: 33.̅3 : In grade school, we'd center the bar above the number. I'm using [LibreWolf](https://librewolf.net/). Like you say, "doesn't print as nicely as advertised".

Answer (score 2):

Does this seem perfect:- 33.3̅ ? Just type an 33.3U+0305 in Libreoffice Writer / Any word processor and Alt+X. Copy 33.3̅ , paste it on the text editor, and you will get this :-

[image]